# Dictionaries inside dictionary not working

Tags: python, dictionary

```
with open('personnages.txt') as file:
my_file = file.read()
f = my_file.split('\n\n')
final_dict = {}

for row1 in f:
    data = row1.strip().split('\n')
    d = {}
    for row2 in data:
        key, value = row2.split(':')
        d[key] = value
        for row3 in d:
            name_dict = {}
            final_dict[d['nom']] = name_dict
            name_dict['genre'] = d['genre']
            name_dict['accessoires'] = d['accessoires']
            name_dict['cheveux'] = d['cheveux']
            name_dict['yeux'] = d['yeux']
            name_dict['nez'] = d['nez']
            name_dict['pilosite'] = d['pilosite']
```

If I print `final_dict` likeso:

```
with open('personnages.txt') as file:
my_file = file.read()
f = my_file.split('\n\n')
final_dict = {}

for row1 in f:
    data = row1.strip().split('\n')
    d = {}
    for row2 in data:
        key, value = row2.split(':')
        d[key] = value
        for row3 in d:
            name_dict = {}
            final_dict[d['nom']] = name_dict
    print(final_dict)
```

it gives

```
{'Alex': {}, 'Alfred': {}, 'Anita': {}, 'Anne': {}, 'Bernard': {}, 'Bill': {}, 'Charles': {}, 'Claire': {}, 'David': {}, 'Eric': {}, 'Frans': {}, 'George': {}, 'Herman': {}, 'Joe': {}, 'Maria': {}, 'Max': {}, 'Paul': {}, 'Peter': {}, 'Philip': {}, 'Richard': {}, 'Robert': {}, 'Sam': {}, 'Susan': {}, 'Tom': {}}
```

Each bracket {} contains a dictionary where the key is `genre`, `accessoires` and value whats on the right. I dont know why its not going beetween the {}.

I'm looking to have this in the output :

```
{'Alex': {'genre': 'homme', 'nez': 'petit', 'yeux': 'bruns'},
 'Alfred': {'genre': 'homme', 'nez': 'gros', 'yeux': 'bleus'},
 'Anita': {'genre': 'femme', 'nez': 'petit', 'yeux': 'bleus'},
 'Anne': {'genre': 'femme', 'nez': 'gros', 'yeux': 'bruns'},
 'Bernard': {'genre': 'homme', 'nez': 'gros', 'yeux': 'bruns'},
 'Bill': {'genre': 'homme', 'nez': 'gros', 'yeux': 'bruns'}}
```

Comment: This code does not print `final_dict`, so when you say "printing final_dict gives ...", you must be referring to other code you haven't shown us.  It's very hard for us to debug code we can't see.

Comment: Hello! Given the nature fo this question, I think there is some missing context.

Comment: Your innermost loop iterates over `d`, but does not use the iteration variable `row3`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah sorry i forgot to precise that when i want to print `final_dict` i delete all the lines after `final_dict[d['nom']] = name_dict`

Comment: In the version where you print `final_dict`, you never add any entries to the inner dictionaries.  Of course, then, they are printed as if they have no entries, because that's accurate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah I know that the inner dictionaries have nothing but my objective is to put pair key:value in them. I'll update the post with what I want to have.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

> ```
>         for row3 in d:
>             name_dict = {}
>             final_dict[d['nom']] = name_dict
> ```

... maps an empty dict to key `d['nom']` in dict `final_dict`.  Multiple times.  Instead, you want to either

1. Collect all the the data for one `'nom'` into a dictionary first, then add that dictionary, OR
2. Add a dictionary for a given `'nom'`, then add entries to *that* dictionary as they are discovered.

If you cannot rely on the `'nom'` entry to be the first read from the file then the former is your best bet.  It might look like this:

```
final_dict = {}

for row1 in f:
    data = row1.strip().split('\n')
    d = {}
    for row2 in data:
        key, value = row2.split(':')
        d[key] = value

    # The whole line has now been parsed
    final_dict[d['nom']] = d

    # Remove the 'nom' entry from the inner dict
    del d['nom']

# print the result (once for all)
print(final_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}}

Comment: But how would I do that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).